# Erro ao aceder à propriedade this.DocumentoPendente TipoEntidade no EditorPendentes

Tags: c#

Agradecia ajuda possível  para ultrapassar o erro:

> this.DocumentoPendente.TipoEntidade =
>   'this.DocumentoPendente.TipoEntidade' gerou uma exceção do tipo
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'

Código:

```
public class PayablesReceivables : EditorPendentes
{
    public override void AntesDeGravar(ref bool Cancel, ExtensibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PSO.Dialogos.MostraAviso(this.DocumentoPendente.TipoEntidade.ToString());
            if ((PSO.Utils.FStr(this.DocumentoPendente.TipoEntidade) == "B") && (PSO.Utils.FStr(this.DocumentoPendente.Tipodoc) == "TLDEP"))
            {
                this.DocumentoPendente.ContaBancaria = this.DocumentoPendente.Entidade;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            PSO.Dialogos.MostraErro(ex.Message, StdPlatBS100.StdBSTipos.IconId.PRI_Exclama, "");
        }

        base.AntesDeGravar(ref Cancel, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @Raposo. Tem a certeza que o erro está aí? É que a linha que está a dar erro não aparece no seu código. Além do que, assim por alto, não me parece que alguma coisa esteja errada aí (pelo menos em termos de tipo de dados).

Comment: Olá. A customização pretendida é basicamente o que publiquei. falta os usings e o namespace "namespace primavera.Logistics.Extensibility". Tenho algum código no editor de vendas e tenho só este no editor de pendentes.

Comment: Certo, mas em que linha dá o erro? Já fez `debug` para tentar perceber?

Comment: @Raposo Isso trata-se uma problema do PRIMAVERA, o objecto que está disponivel para utilização no PEX não está exposto na classe base. Tem de ser reportado à PRIMAVERA.